# jpametamodel null SingularAttribute for String field

Tags: java, jpa, null

I have class entity:

```
@Entity
public class Patient {

   private int id;
   private int mrn;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String middleName;
   private int ssn;
   private Date dateOfBirth;
   private Date dateOfDeath;
   private Sex sex;
   private Set<Visit> visits;
 
 ...
}
```

Usage jpametamodel:

```
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Patient> cq = cb.createQuery(Patient.class);
  Root<Patient> root = cq.from(Patient.class);
  // its work
  Predicate prMrn = cb.equal(root.get(Patient_.MRN), mrn);
  // NullPointerException
  Predicate pFn = cb.equal(root.get(Patient_.firstName), fn);
```

its correct work with Patient_.MRN.
But I have runtime NullPointerException for field Patient_.firstName.

jpametamodel generated with hibernate-jpamodelgen version 5.4.30.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generated class

```
public abstract class Patient_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, String> firstName;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, String> lastName;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Patient, Visit> visits;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, Date> dateOfDeath;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, Integer> MRN;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, String> middleName;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, Date> dateOfBirth;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Patient, Integer> SSN;



// its erorr! right "FirstName"
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    public static final String VISITS = "visits";
    public static final String DATE_OF_DEATH = "dateOfDeath";
    public static final String M_RN = "MRN";
    public static final String MIDDLE_NAME = "middleName";
    public static final String DATE_OF_BIRTH = "dateOfBirth";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String S_SN = "SSN";
}
```

it's work:

```
Predicate pFn = cb.equal(root.get("FirstName"), fn);
```